# How to set G Suite MX records on AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, google-workspace, amazon-lightsail

Normally, with any other DNS management system, you can manage your records by adding a host, content, and type. On AWS Lightsail DNS, it looks like you can only map a subdomain to "yourwebsite.com" with a "maps to" field.

Google mail requires that we set the MX records to aspmx.l.google.com, etc. etc. -- I do not have an option to enter this value into the AWS Lightsail DNS MX records as it only allows me to enter a subdomain to my primary youwebsite.com domain and 'maps to" field.

How do we set up Google mx records on AWS Lightsail DNS?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter `@` or `mail` for the subdomain name, then set to MX and enter your G Suite information (put all five G Suite addresses into one MX record). Don't forget to include the priority.

Your records will look like this:

```
Dns name: mail.example.com.
Type: MX

5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
1 aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

I recommend switching to Route 53 if you understand DNS servers. Lightsail is feature limited (on purpose) to make it easy to get started.

This article will help you configure Lightsail DNS.

[Creating a DNS zone to manage your domain’s DNS records in Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/lightsail-how-to-create-dns-entry)

Answer (score 0):

I just did it at the time I was looking for the answer. Now it's working. Just follow the instructions above about creating a DNS Zone, then just create an MX Record for each one of the Google values:
[Google MX Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfMwp.png)

in the subdomain text box just put @ anything else just put priority and the values.

Answer (score 0):

To add to other responses, don't forget you will find the dns records inside lightsail networking. Pick you domain and add records. This assumes you moved your nameservers to point to your lightsail servers. Once you see this, add the 5 MX records and the one MX record with the verification code. Hope this helps someone that was a bit confused as I was.